# Ionic 1. Doesn't Work HTTP Request

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I have a problem and I don't know how fix it.

I has $http.get() in Ionic and when I do **ionic serve** it works perfect. But when I run ios/android or I see it in Ionic View nothing happens.

My Service:

```
.service('myService', function($rootScope, $http, $q) {
    this.all = function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.get('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
            .success(function(data) {
                deferred.resolve(data);
            })
            .error(function(data) {
                alert(data);
                deferred.reject(data);
            });
        return deferred.promise;
    };
});
```

And in my Controller:

```
myService.all().then(function(data) {
       $scope.data = data;
});
```

When I open in a browser it shows good, and in devices I get the alert with "null".

I do:

Ionic update

Install cordova-plugin-whitelist

Ionic build ios/android -> ionic upload / ionic run

add:

```
<access origin="*" subdomains="true"/>
  <allow-navigation href="http://*/*"/>
```

in config.xml

But nothing work... Any idea?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Take a look at http://content-security-policy.com/

Comment: nothing :/ i don't know what to do

Answer (score 0):

I tried with every site and nothing. It's weird

Update: I add

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'">
```

And the same thing